# How to automate the route creation in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm working in a project who has a file repository system with folders and files. But i dont know how i can do the routes for this system.

For exemple, i have a route to a folder and other to the subfolders, but when i have a third level i have to do a new route for it.

```
Route::name('files.')->prefix('arquivos')->middleware(['auth'])->group(function(){

    Route::get('/', [FileController::class, 'index'])
        ->name('index');

    Route::get('/{folder_slug}', [FileController::class, 'show'])
        ->name('show');
```

I would like to know if is possible to create a process that automate the route creation because i'll have N subfolders in this system.

Thanks for all.

Comment: Please translate your question into English, or ask it at [pt.so]. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have got to use wildcards and a controller that catches your `/` arguments.

```php
Route::get('arquivos/{path}', 'FileController@handle')->where(['path' => '.*']);
```

In your controller you can grab the `$path` variable and eg. split it yourself. Determine if it's a file or a folder, and do whatever you like with it.

```php
public function handle(string $path)
{
    if ($this->someFileService->isDir($path)) {
        $dir = $this->someFileService->getDir($path);
        return view('dir', ['path' => $path, 'dir' => $dir]);
    }
    
    $file = $this->someFileService->getFile($path);
    return view('file', ['path' => $path, 'file' => $file]);  
}
```